# Xcode JSON delegate

Tags: json

I would want the showEventDate method to have the data passed in like the one for the tableview below, how can I do that ? I can't put a indexPath in that method. Thanks.

```
 -(void)showEventDate
{
      EventView *rvc = [[EventView alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventView" bundle:nil];
      [navController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];  
      [rvc release];
}

// Display a details screen for the selected holiday/row.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath             *)indexPath
 {
  Event *holiday = [dataSource holidayAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  HolidaysDetailViewController *vc = [[[HolidaysDetailViewController alloc]              initWithHoliday:holiday] autorelease];
  [navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you want indexRow to be passed from a UITableView to showEventDate. i'm gonna take a stab at it.. u first implement the delegate method, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. then pass 'indexPath' into wherever you want: ie, showEventdate.

```
-(void)showEventPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // your code here...
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self showEventPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: No, the showEventDate is a method to call a button .navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showEventDate)] autorelease];  But when i clicked the button, data wasnt passed in, shown all null value, therefore i need to put an indexpath for the method to push the data into the button